# How to do a bottom UIToolbar with AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm trying to add a `UIToolbar` to the bottom of a screen within my app. But I'm having some difficulties.

This is the code:

```
self.toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, self.view.frame.size.height-44.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0f)];
self.toolBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.toolBar];
```

However, when the device is rotated the `UIToolbar` is offscreen. How do I use `NSAutoLayout` solve this?

Comment: Use autolayout to keep the toolbar where you want it.

Comment: I recommend using storyboard, and set the layout constraints there.

Comment: You are going to want to look into adding NSLayoutConstraints programmatically.

Comment: @Douglas, I've been looking into this for the last two hours. How do I use them to do this?

Comment: i suggest you to use masonry!!! IT is the easier way to add constraints programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add

```
self.toolBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

That will generate the correct constraints, since by default for code-created UIViews, translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is turned on.  A resizing mask of 0 will almost never do what you want, so if you are setting frames yourself, you always need to set the mask correctly as well (since that determines what will happen to the frame when the superview size changes).  The pattern would be 1) set frame; 2) set mask; 3) call addSubview.

Alternatively, you could set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO, don't bother with calculating a frame, and create equivalent layout constraints yourself (height constraint of 44, left/right/bottom constraints to touch the superview).